# OpenGL texture not showing (I don't use shaders)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to texture my models in my project, but nothing works properly. I don't know what wrong is. My code:

```
  //loading the texture:

  unsigned int textureWalls;
  int widthWalls, heightWalls, nrChannelsWalls;
  unsigned char *dataWalls = stbi_load("walls.png", &widthWalls, &heightWalls, &nrChannelsWalls, 0);

  glGenTextures(1, &textureWalls);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureWalls);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, widthWalls, heightWalls, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataWalls);
  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

  // drawing:

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureWalls);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  glVertexPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,0,vertices);
  glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(float)*4,vertexNormals);
  glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,texCoords);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,vertexCount);

  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I try to draw textures for a few models in this way (each model has its own texture), but the textures don't display. Is it necessary to use shaders?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Okay, I edited the post

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing works? What do you see? Also, make sure to make the example *complete*. E.g. what are array contents?

Comment: One possible problem is that you pass `0` as the last parameter for `stbi_load`, but your code relies on getting RGB image from it. You need to pass `3` instead. Another one is that you discard your freshly loaded texture and bind some mysterious `tex` at `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was struggling with it and I forgot to remove that "glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);" in my class. Now it works (even without changing that 0 to 3)

Comment: You should still change it to be safe.